# php separate data using comma then do something for each?

Tags: php, arrays

A string is stored on the database that can have more or less entries. Usually one which isn't an issue but when more than one it would be great to get this working. There isn't a set number of entries (unlimited) therefore asking for second entry etc... wouldn't work on a higher number of entries.

*Any help is much appreciated!*

**PHP Version: 7.2**

```
$string = '649374658494, 74658397464, 746384946354, 8659584748';
$var = explode(',',$string);
foreach($var as &$value){   
    $value = '<p>' .$var. '</p>';
}
```

Comment: You used the mysqli tag but there's no code. I for one don't know what you're asking and what isn't working the way you want it to. Show us what the db schema and values are and if you're checking for errors at all. There are too many unknowns here.

Comment: Don't fill memory like this. If you want to print those values as `P` block, just print them when you need it. for example, `echo '<p>'.$value.'</p>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple mistake. `echo $var` when it should be `$value`.

```
    $string = '649374658494, 74658397464, 746384946354, 8659584748';
    $var = explode(',',$string);
    $nvalue="";
    foreach($var as &$value){   
        $nvalue .= '<p>' .$value. '</p>';
    }
    echo $nvalue;
```

Enabling [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have shown you something like:

> Notice: Array to string conversion...

... and for the sake of avoiding links in answers, you enable simple error reporting like such :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: *"and for the sake of avoiding links in answers, you enable simple error reporting"* - I doubt that PHP.net will change or delete that page ;-) But it's a good addition with the actual code.

Comment: I agree 100% on that one. No offense intended at all. Just simpler to read the answer one time than follow a link.

Comment: Right you are Gavin.

Comment: Thanks but this is still just showing the last entry only, "8659584748" - not all of the entries.

Comment: That's because you were using = and not .= , which is a whole different problem to your original question. I updated the answer.

Comment: You cannot use comments to ask a new question. Mark this answer as correct if it sorted out the original question, then post a new question.

Comment: No problem, I will add the new question when able to.